# Markdown calling helper

Tags: ruby, sinatra, markdown

I have a markdown template for my index page in Sinatra:

```
get '/' do
  markdown :index
end
```

How can I call a Sinatra helper from the Markdown template?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible.

> It is not possible to call methods from markdown, nor to pass locals to it.

But

> You therefore will usually use it in combination with another rendering engine:

Something like this should do the trick

```
%h1 Hello From Haml!
%p= markdown(:greetings)
```

Source: http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/views/markdown